# How can i get a field value in view mode using ClientScript 2.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Im doing a customization and need to get a field value from the screen in view mode using a ClientScript.

I've tried many ways using record and currentrecord Modules.

```
define(['N/record', 'N/currentRecord'], function (currentRecord) {    
    idTransacao = context.currentRecord.getValue({fieldId: 
'internalid'});
}
```

i expect to learn how to handle screen information in view mode using ClientScrip,

Any hel is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've stated dependencies on two modules, `N/record` and `N/currentRecord`, but then only actually parameterized one as `currentRecord`. Then you're interrogating `context.currentRecord` without ever defining anything named `context`.

Recommend watching this tutorial on building your first 2.0 module: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-7HzlhyXNI

Then you'll want to study the API for the `N/currentRecord` module. That is the correct module for working with the record in context within a Client Script. You'll note that the first thing you need to do is retrieve a reference to that record via the module's `get()` method.

However, by default, Client Scripts are not executed in View mode, so what else are you doing that deploys your Client Script to View mode?

Comment: Thank you for the help, i solved the problem getting an parameter from the URL that have the value i need, so i dind't needed do get a field value. @erictgrubaugh